# How to solve unexpected number of root elements issue in alpine js?

Tags: alpine.js

I am working on functionality in alpine js where I need to add a radio button inside the template tag.
Here is what I am doing.

```
<div class="customRadioStyle">
    <template x-for="name in record.names">
        <input type="radio" :value="name.value" :id="name.id">
        <label :for="name.id" x-text="name.value"></label>
    </template>
</div>
```

But this code gives me the following error.

`Alpine: <template> tag with [x-for] encountered with an unexpected number of root elements. Make sure <template> has a single root element.`

Is there any solution for this?

I check this link too but still not able to find a solution for this.
https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/539

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what the error says and make sure there's a single element inside the `<template>`. In you case, you can just add the `<input>` inside the `<label>` or wrap them both with a `<div>`:

```js
window.MyComponent = () => ({
  names: [{
    id: 'name1',
    value: 'Name 1',
  }, {
    id: 'name2',
    value: 'Name 2',
  }, {
    id: 'name3',
    value: 'Name 3',
  }],
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

input {
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div x-data="MyComponent()">
  <template x-for="name in names">
    <label :for="name.id">
      <input type="radio" :value="name.value" :id="name.id" name="radioGroup">
      <span x-text="name.value"></span>
    </label>
  </template>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
```

Note that in the event handler I'm still calling it `e`, but in the HTML I've used `download($event)` instead of `download(e)`.